# d3 conventional indentation with eslint

Tags: javascript, d3.js, eslint

According to the [d3 documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection)

> By convention, selection methods that return the current selection use four spaces of indent, while methods that return a new selection use only two. This helps reveal changes of context by making them stick out of the chain:

Giving code that looks like:

```
d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 960)
    .attr("height", 500)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(20,20)")
  .append("rect")
    .attr("width", 920)
    .attr("height", 460);
```

Is there any way to configure eslint to work with this, so that it doesn't complain about unexpected indentaion levels constantly?

The eslint `indent` [rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/indent) has a `MemberExpression` option so you can ignore all indentation for chained method calls, but I want it enforced, just differently for different methods.  There's also the `ignoredNodes` option which can select certain AST nodes to ignore, but I don't know from the documentation if that can select to the fidelity I want.  While disabling checking for certain chained methods is not great, it is better than nothing.  In that case, I doubt this is a comprehensive list, but all the ones I'm using at four-space indentation are:

```
.attr()
.style()
.text()
.call()
.on()
```

So some way to ignore chained method calls with exactly those names, and leave all others at two-space would be an OK stop-gap measure (including methods totally unrelated to d3).

Edit: Removed `.data()` and `.enter()` from the list as Gerardo Furtado pointed out they return new selections.

Comment: You'll probably have to either look for a plugin someone has already created or make one yourself that will enforce 2 spaces (tab) in most cases but enforce 4 spaces (2 tabs) for method names provided to the plugin.

Comment: I did a search for plugins, I could find anything though web searching or from the awesome-eslint list. I was worried I might have to go the way of writing my own, but did think it was odd no-one had tried to use idiomatic d3 was with eslint before.

Comment: Just FYI, `data` and `enter` return a new selection.

Answer (score 1):

I would focus it differently for 2 reasons:

1. **Consistent coding convention across all JavaScript elements**
   which we may develop
2. **Automation**

As a user of the cross-platform multi-language open-source IDE **Visual Studio Code**, and since there are highly valuable Visual Studio Code extensions like **[JS-CSS-HTML Formatter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lonefy.vscode-JS-CSS-HTML-formatter)** (Id: lonefy.vscode-js-css-html-formatter, current working version 0.2.3), I write code and it indents automatically when needed.

For this particular case, we would use that extension to **modify Javascript code on every save, automatically**, as it formats code with a decent convention.

I had the workaround of adding built-in commented regions (marked in gray) so that you can **help on code visualizing in a similar manner as indent does** when folding the code, and this would be the result after saving:

```
d3.select("body")
    //#region svg
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 960)
    .attr("height", 500)
    //#endregion
    //#region g
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(20,20)")
    //#endregion
    //#region rect
    .append("rect")
    .attr("width", 920)
    .attr("height", 460)
    //#endregion
;
```

This is not showing the desired formatting, but here is the trick:

It displays only the green colored **//#region inner elements lines** when folded, and all inner elements when unfolded

I hope it helps, at least for a consistent and automated convention across your development situations.

JGB